# (LibGDX Android) Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx, classnotfoundexception

I have imported the projects created by gdx-setup in Eclipse. There is no error but when I tried to launch the application in my phone or in an emulator, the app crash and I have these messages in my Logcat :
[Logcat.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlV9D.png)
Here is my code in my android class :

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;
import com.mygdx.game.MyGdxGame;

public class AndroidGame extends AndroidApplication {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        initialize(new MyGdxGame(), config);
    }
}
```

[Here is my android buildpath.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xzgel.png)

I know this is a common problem but I've tried many solutions and nothing work.
Sorry for the bad english.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Since the default name for Android starter class in AndroidLauncher I assume you renamed it to AndroidGame and some important parts in the code where not updated:

/android/build.gradle:

Look for line like this:
`commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'de.tomgrill.someandroidpackage.android/de.tomgrill.android.AndroidLauncher'`

The part before the / must match the package name in the AndroidManifest.xml

In my case:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.tomgrill.someandroidpackage.android"
......
```

The part after the / must match the AndroidLauncher class incl. package.

here: `de.tomgrill.android.AndroidLauncher`

package: `de.tomgrill.android`

class: `AndroidLauncher`

Also make sure that the launcher class for the activity in your AndroidManifest.xml fits:

```
<application
        ...... >
        <activity
            android:name="de.tomgrill.android.AndroidLauncher"
           .....>
            <intent-filter>
                <...... />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```